# determine if client has closed connection to server using socket

Tags: php, apache, sockets, ubuntu, websocket

I am attempting to check if the client has lost connection so that I can close the clients connection allowing the client to reconnect.

I have the following.

```
$socket = @socket_create_listen("12345");

while (true) {  
    $client = socket_accept($socket);
    socket_write($client, 'hello');
    while (true) {
        //Code to exit this loop when client looses connection
        socket_write($client, '');
        echo socket_last_error($socket);
    }
    socket_close($client);  
}
```

Attempt:

[1]Writing an empty string to the client hoping this would generate an error if the client was disconnected but this didn't work.

[2] Using the ocket_select

```
$r = array($socket);
$w = NULL;
$e = NULL;
if (false === socket_select($r, $w, $e, 0)) {
    echo "socket_select() failed, reason: " .
        socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
```

This also didn't seem to generate an error then the client lost connection.

Notes: Im trying to accomplish this on the server side thus sending a bit and waiting for a reply is not really what i'm after. Typically I just writing to the client and not receiving data thus running my code in blocking hasn't been an issue because I am normally writing and not reading.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is how I solved it:

```
$result = socket_read($socket,2000);

if ($result === "") {
      // it goes in here when the socket (host) has disconnected
}
else {
     // it goes in here when the buffer is empty or the buffer has data in it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I believe can be used to detect exiting socket...

Originator of this code was stated as **Andrew Gillard** no other licence information was available...

```
<?php

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 7010;
gc_enable();

set_time_limit(0);

function socketError($errorFunction, $die=false)
{
    $errMsg = socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    echo $errorFunction.' '.$errMsg."\n";
    if ($die) die("Program Ended\n");
}

//Attempt to create our socket. The "@" hides PHP's standard error reporting,
if (!($server = @socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP))) socketError('socket_create', true);
//socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
if (!@socket_bind($server, $host, $port)) socketError('socket_bind', true);
if (!@socket_listen($server)) socketError('socket_listen', true);
 //Create an array to store our sockets in. We use this so that we can
// determine which socket has new incoming data with the "socket_select()"
// function, and to properly close each socket when the script finishes
$allSockets = array($server);

while (true) {
    //We have to echo something to the browser or PHP won't know if the Stop button has been pressed
    //echo ' ';
    //if ( connection_aborted() ) {
        //The Stop button has been pressed, so close all our sockets and exit
        //foreach ($allSockets as $socket) socket_close($socket);
        //break;
    //}

    //socket_select() is slightly strange. You have to make a copy of the array
    // of sockets you pass to it, because it changes that array when it returns
    // and the resulting array will only contain sockets with waiting data on
    // them. $write and $except are set to NULL because we aren't interested in
    // them. The last parameter indicates that socket_select will return after
    // that many seconds if no data is receiveed in that time; this prevents the
    // script hanging forever at this point (remember, we might want to accept a
    // new connection or even exit entirely) and also pauses the script briefly
    // to prevent this tight while() loop using a lot of processor time
    $changedSockets = $allSockets;
    @socket_select($changedSockets, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 10);

    //Now we loop over each of the sockets that socket_select() says have new
    // data on them
    foreach($changedSockets as $socket) {
        if ($socket == $server) {
            //socket_select() will include our server socket in the
            // $changedSockets array if there is an incoming connection attempt
            // on it. This will only accept one incoming connection per while()
            // loop iteration, but that shouldn't be a problem given the
            // frequency that we're iterating
            if (!($client = @socket_accept($server))) {
                socketError('socket_accept', false);
            } else {
                //Accepted incoming connection, add new client socket to our array of sockets
                @socket_set_nonblock($client);
                $allSockets[] = $client;
            }
            echo "Accepted: allSockets count = ".count($allSockets)." memory: ".memory_get_usage()."\n";
        } else {
            //Attempt to read data from this socket
            echo "socket read start\n"; //DEBUG
            $data = @socket_read($socket, 1024);
            echo "socket read end\n"; //DEBUG
            if ($data === false || $data === '') {
                //socket_read() returned FALSE, meaning that the client has
                // closed the connection. Therefore we need to remove this
                // socket from our client sockets array and close the socket
                //A potential bug in PHP means that socket_read() will return
                // an empty string instead of FALSE when the connection has
                // been closed, contrary to what the documentation states. As
                // such, we look for FALSE or an empty string (an empty string
                // for the current, buggy, behaviour, and FALSE in case it ends
                // up getting fixed at some point)
                unset($allSockets[array_search($socket, $allSockets)]);
                @socket_close($socket);
                echo "$socket closed, number left = ".count($allSockets)."\n";
            } else {
                //We got useful data from socket_read()
                echo "$socket [".count($allSockets)." - ".memory_get_usage(). "] wrote: $data\n";

                // ADD YOUR DATA HANDLER HERE
            }
        }
    }
} // end while

?>
```